# Google Drive Web hook don't work without any error

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I use python and google-api-python-client==1.6.2 to work with user Google Drive's. Everything works perfectly without any bugs, but I didn't receive any push notification from Google Drive ([Google Drive API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/push)). "Registering your domain" successfully completed. "Creating notification channels" completed with Channel object returning to me.

My code:

```
try:
    drive_service.files().watch(
        fileId='CPw3cbyqkoC1QMK48R24-Z2CG9w',
        body=dict(
            id=str(uuid.uuid4()),
            resourceId='CPw3cbyqkoC1QMK48R24-Z2CG9w',
            type='web_hook',
            address='https://my-domain-address/web_hook'
        )
    ).execute()
except HttpError as err:
    logger.exception('HttpError {}: content={}'.format(err.uri, err.content))
```

Response:

```
{
    u'resourceId': u'CPw3cbyqkoC1QMK48R24-Z2CG9w',
    u'kind': u'api#channel',
    u'expiration': u'1495448262000',
    u'id': u'8837a4ad-98c0-4e89-8899-c07e12e3bffc',
    u'resourceUri': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B2lHB_g_GJY9RWx6UkRjWUFjSVU?acknowledgeAbuse=false&alt=json&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json'
}
```

After it there are not any requests to `https://my-domain-address/web_hook` when User modify watched Google Drive resource.

Have you any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I use Google Drive API v3.

Comment: I found the problem. I did not receive anything to webhook, because these all requests was blocked by nginx, that is returning 403 status code. So, thanks all. I found the problem source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log messages linked with the problem that I found while search a solution:

```
64.233.172.141 - - [22/May/2017:09:11:10 +0000] "POST /web_hook HTTP/1.1" 403 807 "-" "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)"
64.233.172.143 - - [22/May/2017:09:11:12 +0000] "POST /web_hook HTTP/1.1" 403 807 "-" "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)"
64.233.172.143 - - [22/May/2017:09:11:13 +0000] "POST /web_hook HTTP/1.1" 403 807 "-" "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)"
```

So I'm receiving the Google Drive requests to my webhook.

Firstly I think that `Nginx` is blocking them, but after I had seen that all requests are `POST`.

So I came to the problem of forwarding POST requests. Also I use Django and forgot disable CSRF protection to webhook. This is a solution of my problem.

I'll be glad if it helps someone.